# Объект в двух таблицах

Tags: python, django

Есть набор объектов: Obj1, Obj2, Obj3. У них есть какие-то общие параметры и какие-то специфичные для каждого типа. Общие хранятся в одной таблице common_parameters, а специфичные в params1, params2 и params3 соответственно.
Подскажите, как бы так описать классы модели, чтобы каждый класс содержал как общие поля так и специфичные, ну и чтобы при сохранении апдейтить две таблицы?
Если такое вообще возможно.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если я правильно понимаю, то вам подойдет [наследование моделей](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/db/models/#multi-table-inheritance)

```
class Common(models.Model):
    common_param_1 =
    common_param_2 =

class Obj1(Common):
    spec_param_1 =
    spec_param_2 =

class Obj1(Common):
    spec_param_1 =
    spec_param_2 =
```

Между моделями неявно создается связь один-к-одному.

Comment: спасибо, то что нужно

Answer (score 0):

Можно связывать через ForeignKey, у объекта будет 3 поля с внешними ключами и допустимо значение NULL. Получается громоздно, зато условие выполнено: объект может иметь свойства из любых трёх таблиц params1-3.
Честно говоря, мне не нравится предложенный мной вариант, но ничего другого на ум не идёт.